# Using std::find to find chars read from binary file and cast to a std::string in a std::vector<string> creates this inpredictible behaviour?

Tags: c++, c++11

Sorry for the long headline. I couldn't know how to describe it in short words.

Would you care to recreate the problem i am going through?

You can use any wav file to read.

I am trying to query the chunks in a wav file here, this is the simplified version of the code, but i think it might be enough to recreate if there is a problem.

I use a mac, and compile with `g++ -std=c++11`.

When i run this code and don't include the line `std::cout << query << std::endl;` then `std::find(chunk_types.begin(), chunk_types.end(), query) != chunk_types.end()` returns 0 in all iterations. But i know the binary file contains some of these chunks. If i include the line then it works properly, but that is also not predictable lets say it works properly sometimes.

I am a bit perplexed am i doing anything wrong here?

```
#include <fstream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector> 

int main(){    

    std::vector<std::string> chunk_types{
    "RIFF","WAVE","JUNK","fmt ","data","bext",
    "cue ","LIST","minf","elm1",
    "slnt","fact","plst","labl","note",
    "adtl","ltxt","file"};

    std::streampos fileSize;
    std::ifstream file(/* file path here */, std::ios::binary);
    file.seekg(0, std::ios::beg);

    char fileData[4];

    for(int i{0};i<100;i+=4){ //100 is an arbitrary number

        file.seekg(i);
        file.read((char*) &fileData[0], 4);
        std::string query(fileData);

        std::cout << query << std::endl;

        /* if i put this std::cout here, it works or else std::find always returns 0 */


        if( std::find(chunk_types.begin(), chunk_types.end(), query) != chunk_types.end() ){ 
           std::cout << "found " + query << std::endl; 
        } 

    }

return 0;

}
```

Comment: Is `fileData` null-terminated? Is the last character a `\0`? Constructing a string with it otherwise is going to cause UB

Comment: Side-note: This is a case where a `std::vector`+`std::find` is probably the wrong way to go. Membership testing against a large set of values with exact equality semantics is best done with `std::unordered_set` (pre-C++11, `std::set`) and its `find` method, which makes the membership test roughly `O(1)`, rather than `O(n)`.

Comment: Thank you, i will look in to it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`std::string query(fileData)` uses `strlen` on `fileData` to find its terminating 0, but doesn't find one because `fileData` is not zero-terminated and continues searching for 0 up the stack until it finds it or hits inaccessible memory past the end of the stack and causes `SIGSEGV`.

Also `file.read` can read fewer symbols than expected, `gcount` must be used to extract the actual number of characters last read:

A fix:

```
file.read(fileData, sizeof fileData);
auto len = file.gcount();
std::string query(fileData, len);
```

A slightly more efficient solution is to read directly into `std::string` and keep reusing it to avoid a memory allocation (if no short string optimisation) and copying:

```
std::string query;
// ...
    constexpr int LENGTH = 4;
    query.resize(LENGTH);
    file.read(&query[0], LENGTH);
    query.resize(file.gcount());
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed explanation and working solution. I would also probably add more logic to check if the right `gcount` has read also, and if not seek back and try to read again.

Comment: It's important to note that if `fileData` can contain shorter strings you may not get exactly the behavior you expect. But since `chunk_types` only contains 4 character strings this doesn't seem to be the case. This gives you a string of exactly 4 characters, even if `fileData` would contain a null terminator. This null terminator will be part of the string's value.

Comment: Arguably, `query.resize(file.gcount());` should really just be `if (file.gcount() != LENGTH) break;`, since the code logic only applies when the full four character chunk was read.

Comment: @ShadowRanger It is also a good stop condition on EOF and read error.

Comment: You give me a lot to check and study genuinely thank you. Just from curiosity, do you have an idea why it worked most of the time when i used std::cout to print the contents of query to stdo ? I understand that this is undefined behaviour but it worked much more often when i included that line.

Comment: @AliSomay `strlen` can find a 0 nearby up in the stack. 0 bytes are quite frequent in the stack, e.g. any 64-byte pointer has two 0 bytes, any integer at least 256 times smaller than its max value.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin giving `query.data()` as first argument to `file.read()` creates this compiler error. `error: cannot initialize a parameter of type 'char_type *' (aka 'char *') with an rvalue
      of type 'const value_type *' (aka 'const char *')` do we need a type conversion there ?

Comment: @AliSomay Oops, that requires C++17. Use `&query[0]` instead of `query.data()`.